# Ошибка при первичной компиляции Compilation failed

Tags: android-studio

Кто нибудь встречался с такой ошибкой `Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.`. Причем при повторном нажатии на запуск (Run app), отлично компилируется и не выдает ни каких ошибок.

Comment: да у меня такая проблема была при построении проекта, в output нашлись какие-то непонятные файлы к которым осуществлялось обращение. После удаления этих файлов такая ошибка пропала. Я бы вам посоветовал посмотреть сам отчет ошибок, там очень все хорошо показано. Студия иногда может самостоятельно создавать проблемы на пустом месте.

Comment: К сожалению не помогло((

Comment: а вы заходили, смотрели отчет о ошибках?

Comment: `Unable to instantiate application android.app.Application: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to get package info for example.ru.myapp; is package not installed?`

Comment: вы это откуда взяли?

Comment: При компиляции выдаёт в логах

Comment: та не)) в логах я честно говоря не сильно пока силен, если что то будем разбираться, я вам говорил чтобы вы посмотрели в отчет построения, он в проекте находится в папке output